# Javascript graphic counter. How I could do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

take a look to this site: http://www.zombiepandemic.com/

I like very much the js counter. I tried for some time to learn fromt that site how they did realize it and i cannot solve my doubt.

i.e. jQuery move single number stripe to accomodate the final number, but... how is possibile that after (e.g.):

> 1099

entire js move correctly last 2 in bottom and 2nd one one step top to obtain:

> 1100

Comment: So you're not asking for the animation, but the logic to switch from 1099 to 1100?

Comment: I would like (entire) logic.... with also a similar tutorial..... or btw something that could place me on correct way...

Comment: There are many different ways to achieve that, but it should be quite simple. What have you tried?

Comment: i'm at start... I don't know how set up it... where to watch... :(

Comment: Take a look at this script. It's well commented and is functionally very similar to your example (moving image strips around based on the count): http://www.fogtower.com/products/javascript-number-counter/

Comment: OK, it doesn't have image but seems similar to my example. Good starting point, i think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along these lines should do it:

```
var count = 1098;
function increment(){
    count++
    return count.toString(10).split('');
}


> increment()
["1", "0", "9", "9"]
> increment()
["1", "1", "0", "0"]
```

Comment: +1 Yep this is a great place to start. You can iterate over that array each time increment is invoked to assign the proper placement of the image strips no problem.